# classifier.setOptions( weka.core.Utils.splitOptions()) is taking only default values even if other values provided in matlab

Tags: matlab, weka

```
import weka.core.Instances.*

filename = 'C:\Users\Girish\Documents\MATLAB\DRESDEN_NSC.csv';
loader = weka.core.converters.CSVLoader();
loader.setFile(java.io.File(filename));
data = loader.getDataSet();
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);

%% classification
classifier = weka.classifiers.trees.J48();
classifier.setOptions( weka.core.Utils.splitOptions('-C 0.25 -M 2') );
classifier.buildClassifier(data);
classifier.toString()

ev = weka.classifiers.Evaluation(data);

v(1) = java.lang.String('-t');
v(2) = java.lang.String(filename);
v(3) = java.lang.String('-split-percentage');
v(4) = java.lang.String('66');
prm = cat(1,v(1:4));
ev.evaluateModel(classifier, prm)

Result:
Time taken to build model: 0.04 seconds
Time taken to test model on training split: 0.01 seconds

=== Error on training split ===

Correctly Classified Instances         767               99.2238 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances         6                0.7762 %
Kappa statistic                          0.9882
Mean absolute error                      0.0087
Root mean squared error                  0.0658
Relative absolute error                  1.9717 %
Root relative squared error             14.042  %
Total Number of Instances              773     


=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0.994    0.009    0.987      0.994    0.990      0.984    0.999     0.999     Nikon
                 1.000    0.000    1.000      1.000    1.000      1.000    1.000     1.000     Sony
                 0.981    0.004    0.990      0.981    0.985      0.980    0.999     0.997     Canon
Weighted Avg.    0.992    0.004    0.992      0.992    0.992      0.988    1.000     0.999     


=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   <-- classified as
 306   0   2 |   a = Nikon
   0 258   0 |   b = Sony
   4   0 203 |   c = Canon


=== Error on test split ===

Correctly Classified Instances         358               89.9497 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances        40               10.0503 %
Kappa statistic                          0.8482
Mean absolute error                      0.0656
Root mean squared error                  0.2464
Relative absolute error                 14.8485 %
Root relative squared error             52.2626 %
Total Number of Instances              398     


=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0.885    0.089    0.842      0.885    0.863      0.787    0.908     0.832     Nikon
                 0.993    0.000    1.000      0.993    0.997      0.995    0.997     0.996     Sony
                 0.796    0.060    0.841      0.796    0.818      0.749    0.897     0.744     Canon
Weighted Avg.    0.899    0.048    0.900      0.899    0.899      0.853    0.938     0.867     


=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   <-- classified as
 123   0  16 |   a = Nikon
   0 145   1 |   b = Sony
  23   0  90 |   c = Canon




import weka.core.Instances.*

filename = 'C:\Users\Girish\Documents\MATLAB\DRESDEN_NSC.csv';
loader = weka.core.converters.CSVLoader();
loader.setFile(java.io.File(filename));
data = loader.getDataSet();
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);

%% classification
classifier = weka.classifiers.trees.J48();
classifier.setOptions( weka.core.Utils.splitOptions('-C 0.1 -M 1') );
classifier.buildClassifier(data);
classifier.toString()

ev = weka.classifiers.Evaluation(data);


v(1) = java.lang.String('-t');
v(2) = java.lang.String(filename);
v(3) = java.lang.String('-split-percentage');
v(4) = java.lang.String('66');

prm = cat(1,v(1:4));
ev.evaluateModel(classifier, prm)

Result:
Time taken to build model: 0.04 seconds
Time taken to test model on training split: 0 seconds

=== Error on training split ===

Correctly Classified Instances         767               99.2238 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances         6                0.7762 %
Kappa statistic                          0.9882
Mean absolute error                      0.0087
Root mean squared error                  0.0658
Relative absolute error                  1.9717 %
Root relative squared error             14.042  %
Total Number of Instances              773     


=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0.994    0.009    0.987      0.994    0.990      0.984    0.999     0.999     Nikon
                 1.000    0.000    1.000      1.000    1.000      1.000    1.000     1.000     Sony
                 0.981    0.004    0.990      0.981    0.985      0.980    0.999     0.997     Canon
Weighted Avg.    0.992    0.004    0.992      0.992    0.992      0.988    1.000     0.999     


=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   <-- classified as
 306   0   2 |   a = Nikon
   0 258   0 |   b = Sony
   4   0 203 |   c = Canon


=== Error on test split ===

Correctly Classified Instances         358               89.9497 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances        40               10.0503 %
Kappa statistic                          0.8482
Mean absolute error                      0.0656
Root mean squared error                  0.2464
Relative absolute error                 14.8485 %
Root relative squared error             52.2626 %
Total Number of Instances              398     


=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0.885    0.089    0.842      0.885    0.863      0.787    0.908     0.832     Nikon
                 0.993    0.000    1.000      0.993    0.997      0.995    0.997     0.996     Sony
                 0.796    0.060    0.841      0.796    0.818      0.749    0.897     0.744     Canon
Weighted Avg.    0.899    0.048    0.900      0.899    0.899      0.853    0.938     0.867     


=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   <-- classified as
 123   0  16 |   a = Nikon
   0 145   1 |   b = Sony
  23   0  90 |   c = Canon
```

Same Result with both split options which is the result for default options i.e. -C 0.25 -M 2 for J48 classifier

please help!!! stuck here for a long time.Tried Different means but nothing worked for me

Comment: Is it possible that the options are being accepted, but that changing their values does not change the tree?  I would look at the [.getOptions](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html#getOptions--) method.  This will tell you if your values are accepted.  I would also try very extreme values to see if that has an affect on the results.

Comment: I have used weka version 3-6 for it,I think it is neglecting the classifier.setOptions( weka.core.Utils.splitOptions('-C 0.25 -M 2') ); line and taking as default because if I provide something else like any random text it is giving the same output.while with higher version of weka like 3-7,3-8 it is checking for parameters to match not just a random text either way it is giving the default output